# get path of source file when compiling from another directory

Tags: luatex

Is it possible to get the absolute path of the main tex file when compiled from another directory? LuaTeX is the engine I use, so a LuaTeX-only soluion is fine.

If I have `/x/y/test.tex` and if I do `cd /x/y/z` then `luatex ../test.tex`, `\jobname` will be `test`, and `lfs.currentdir()` gives `/x/y/z`, so I cannot compute `/x/y/test.tex` with only these two informations...

The goal is to make some relative path working even when compiled from a different directory.

Comment: It's not really recommended to use relative paths: you won't be able to write auxiliary files, if you do.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment... do you mean that `\input chapter1/main.tex` should be avoided? It seems quite a common practice... Now, as it is common practice, many users of [Gregorio](gregorio.cc) are using it, especially since many use gregorio to compile books of more than 1000 pages with around 2000 includes, I cannot tell them "just put all your 4000 files in the same dir"...

Comment: No, but try with `\include`.

Comment: Gregorio is using \include in fact... Well, let's be more specific: GregorioTeX (when authorized to shell-escape) is automatically compiling `myscore.gabc` scores into `myscore-api-yyyymmdd.tex` which it then includes. `yyyymmdd` corresponds to the api number; the goal being to recompile scores if GregorioTeX has an api number greater than the one of the corresponding file. It works well if the compilation takes place in the directory of the main `.tex` file, but in order to use this mechanism,...

Comment: I have to get informations about the files that will be included, which I can't do without the information about the directory of the main `.tex` file. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

An answer is to parse command line arguments in lua, see [this post](http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2015-March/005104.html) :

```
\directlua{
    print()
    print("currentdir:"..lfs.currentdir())
    texio.write_nl("")
    for k, v in ipairs(arg) do
        texio.write_nl(k .. " " .. v)
    end
    texio.write_nl("")
     }

\bye
```